# What is the actual order of execution when Top-K, Top-P and Temperature are used together for NLP decoding?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

Let's say I use:

```
sample_outputs = model.generate(**model_inputs,max_new_tokens=40,do_sample=True,
    top_k=3,top_p=0.51, temperature=0.6, num_return_sequences=3,)
```

What is the order of execution in this one?
Looked at the code for [labml.ai](https://nn.labml.ai/sampling/experiment.html) sampling example and it doesn't make sense because when using Temperature with top-K or Top-P, it first uses Softmax and selects and then use the `Sampler`

In the [Google Cloud Document](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/model-reference/text#:%7E:text=For%20each%20token%20selection%20step,value%20for%20more%20random%20responses.), it says that you use Top-K then Filter with Top-P along with Temperature.

Let's say your **`PROBABILITIES`** as t0→0.4 , t1→0.2, t2→0.2, t3→0.15, t4→0.05`

You use `Top-K = 3` and now you have `t0,t1,t2`. Now you have 2 choices:

1. Whether to apply `Top-P = 0.51` and then you again Normalize
2. Or Normalize first then Apply `Top-P = 0.51` and then again Normalize

On top of it, if we use `temperature = 0.6` do we apply it in beginning? If yeas, then it is different when we would have used on just `Top-P` because the distribution has been shifted already.

How does that work? Can someone please explain in terms of execution?